# How to integrate Ionic 4 + AngularJS (1.7.2) + Webpack + Cordova?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, webpack

Ionic 4 CLI is seems to be friendly only with Angular7. And Angular7 is slow like.. send for compile and go take a shower and back and maybe the bundle will be ready. Actually the worst framework the front end ever met.

AngularJS is probably the best happened to front end world. Everything is fast, reliable, straight forward. When you combine this with Webpack you can enjoy an high level of programming language including exports and imports and classes and and components just everything else you need.

However, the Ionic CLI doesn't integrated with something else than the Angular7.

So I have tried to create a **cordova** based project using:

```
cordova create test
```

And then tried to "manually" setting things up.

I have installed Webpack in the cordova based project so now it's accessiable through the node_modules folder. Then I have created the **webpack.config.js** file in the same directory.
Then I have created **src** directory which stores the **webpack.entry.js** file. The webpack.config file reads what the entry file created and creates a new folder called www and there it places index.html file and bundle.js.

Then I am trying to run **cordova run --device** with Android device connected and the app is getting actioned in the actual device.
Very nice.

However, I have some issues: it seems that the files that are in the bundle doesn't going to be work since angularjs is not completely served.
I mean, in order to serve an angularjs app you probably need a static server or serve it via node. In this case this doesn't happening so it just like drag the index.html file to the Chrome browser and have it not working at all.

I have searched tons at Google but found just nothing.

Is there any boilerplate working with Cordova + Webpack + AngularJs + Ionic framework's components, working fast with livereload?

Comment: Why not just try Ionic v1? `ionic start myApp --type=ionic1`

Comment: @SimonL.Brazell Thats a good idea.